# CREATE TABLE query with SELECT having NOT NULL fields

Tags: mysql

I tried searching on this topic but I couldn't find any help on it. I want to write a `CREATE TABLE` query with `SELECT` having `NOT NULL` fields. The query I am using to create the table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_tsLiLpLgIspFiFp
SELECT timeStamp, localIp, localport, localgeo, isp, foreignip, foreignPort,
COUNT(*) AS `countSamefPort`
FROM union_of_outbound_threats
GROUP BY timeStamp, localIp, localport, localgeo, isp, foreignip, foreignPort;
```

I want the fields to be set as `NOT NULL`. What extra parameters should I add? If this was addressed before please direct me to it :)

Comment: if you need the results that doesn't contain nulls you just need to specify a condition in where clause

Comment: the thing is i want the empty results, BUT need to specify the column constraint to NOT NULL on the new table:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how MySQL could know anything about the content of your columns, unless you were basing the CREATE on another table ("LIKE ...").

It couldn't know anything about primary keys, default values, foreign keys, etc, right?

Looks like you're stuck doing an ALTER TABLE afterwards.

Comment: ohh..i seee :) thank you for pointing that out :) i thought it was possible as in specifying the constraints on the select statement itself for example :) thanks again